# Concurrent queries in Postgres

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, deadlock

I'll try shortly describe what I have to understand purpose of this question. 
I have large multi-thread application developed in Java. Each thread has hard logic to load, validate and parse the file and then insert this data into database. The stage of inserts/updates database in thread too. Each thread runs several stored procedures which updates one table. These stored proc is a several for each thread.

This database is used by a web application at the same time. So as you understood I have problem with deadlock. I tried all of lock model but any of them did not help me. In some timeframe SELECT from web works long time.

What is my question after all. Have postgres mechanism/means to synchronize stored procedure or query? I know it must done by means of a lock model, but I've had no success. As a solution for MS Server, I use "WITH NOLOCK" for SELECT statements. I can resolve this by means code synchronize, but it's really complicated logic.

By request I post example of slow query in updating process.

```
SELECT c.id AS id,cn.name as name,c.parent_category_id AS parent_category_id,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT p.id FROM category AS subcat
  INNER JOIN product AS p ON subcat.id = p.category_id
  WHERE subcat.parent_category_id=c.id LIMIT 1)
 THEN true ELSE false END AS autoupdate
        FROM category AS c
        INNER JOIN category_name AS cn ON c.id=cn.category_id
        LEFT JOIN category AS subcat ON subcat.parent_category_id = c.id
        WHERE c.parent_category_id=0AND cn.langid=1 AND c.id != 1
        AND EXISTS
            (SELECT p.id FROM product AS p
            WHERE p.category_id = c.id OR p.category_id = subcat.id LIMIT 1)
        GROUP BY c.sort,c.id,cn.name,c.parent_category_id
        ORDER BY c.sort, cn.name`
```

And explain:

```
'Group  (cost=947.74..987.96 rows=15 width=40)'
'  ->  Sort  (cost=947.74..947.75 rows=15 width=40)'
'        Sort Key: c.sort, cn.name, c.id, c.parent_category_id'
'        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=125.84..947.62 rows=15 width=40)'
'              Merge Cond: (c.id = subcat.parent_category_id)'
'              Filter: (SubPlan 2)'
'              ->  Sort  (cost=64.46..64.46 rows=3 width=40)'
'                    Sort Key: c.id'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..64.45 rows=3 width=40)'
'                          ->  Seq Scan on category c  (cost=0.00..41.69 rows=3 width=18)'
'                                Filter: ((id  1) AND (parent_category_id = 0))'
'                          ->  Index Scan using category_name_category_id_langid on category_name cn  (cost=0.00..7.56 rows=1 width=30)'
'                                Index Cond: ((cn.category_id = c.id) AND (cn.langid = 1))'
'              ->  Sort  (cost=61.38..62.46 rows=1084 width=16)'
'                    Sort Key: subcat.parent_category_id'
'                    ->  Seq Scan on category subcat  (cost=0.00..39.52 rows=1084 width=16)'
'              SubPlan 2'
'                ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..27.29 rows=1 width=8)'
'                      ->  Seq Scan on product p  (cost=0.00..36459.98 rows=1336 width=8)'
'                            Filter: ((category_id = $0) OR (category_id = $1))'
'  SubPlan 1'
'    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..2.68 rows=1 width=8)'
'          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..17889.28 rows=6684 width=8)'
'                ->  Seq Scan on category subcat  (cost=0.00..40.60 rows=10 width=8)'
'                      Filter: (parent_category_id = $0)'
'                ->  Index Scan using product_category_id on product p  (cost=0.00..1764.16 rows=668 width=16)'
'                      Index Cond: (p.category_id = subcat.id)'
```

Thanks!
Best regards
Artem

Comment: Thanks for the query plan, but I didn't ask for `EXPLAIN query`; I asked for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query`. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the term you're looking for is "[isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html)". I'd imagine that some parts of your application might tolerate dirty reads, unrepeatable reads, or phantom reads. But in current versions of PostgreSQL, [writers don't block readers, and readers don't block writers](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2001/05/25/postgresql_mvcc.html).

So my question is this: How do you know the delay is caused by a lock, and not by, say, disk I/O, connection load, other processes (processes not related to the dbms, like a long-running cron job), or something else?

Comment: Only one application updates database. So any other "job" can't do it.  When application is stopped never have not select query with long time. And select query take a "long time" if updates the same table which for select. I tried monitor lock by means PgAdmin. btw, I uses posgres9

Comment: Edit your original question, and post the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query`, where "query" is the SELECT statement you run from the web.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need "WITH NOLOCK" in PostgreSQL as readers will never be blocked by writers. The only way to block a SELECT on a table is manually lock the table with exclusive access - which is not something that is done by normal DML statements. Only an ALTER TABLE will acquire such a lock.

But I'm not sure I understood your question though.

Do you already *have* a problem with deadlocks? Or do you think you will have them, without testing?

Comment: I already have deadlock. Postgres write that I'll never have problem with select. But on practical it's not true. In update process simple query works very long time(but not more then update process). I mean select from the same table which is update at the same time.

Comment: A select while an update is running will not be blocked unless you use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. Did you check the locks while the application is running?

Comment: Yep, application works on production sever, and was complaint that time to time some operations works slow. After additional investigate I determinate that select is working slow when is working update of this table. If i'm not mistaken `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` uses back to frontfor to lock for update. For simple example : `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = column1 *10` and the same time execute `SELECT * FROM teble1`

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do. When using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` you are basically telling Postgres that you are smarter when it comes to locking. The only way to avoid this is to remove the `FOR UPDATE`